# org-mode-hook is always evaluated

Tags: org-mode, init-file, hooks, themes

I'd like [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode) to use a particular theme. To this end, I've put the following in my `init.el`:

```
;; Setup org-mode theme
(defun org_setup()
  "Setup org-mode"
  (load-theme 'doom-laserwave)
  )

;; Startup hook for org-mode
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (org_setup))
```

Curiously, *whatever* file I open (e.g., even `init.el`) this theme is used. Why is that? My (limited) understanding is that this code should only be run if `org-mode` is initiated. Am I doing something daft?

Comment: Does it happen with `emacs -q -l minimal.el` and a minimal init file that just contains the above code? If not, bisect your init file to figure out who the culprit is.

Comment: With just the code above I get `Unable to find theme file for ‘doom-laserwave’`.

Comment: I need more coffee: @lawlist saw the problem exactly. As an explanation, `(func)` calls the function, so what you are doing is calling the function and adding its return value to the hook. What you want to do instead is add the function itself to the hook, so it can be called later.

Comment: @NickD Ah, I see. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the O.P. meant to use an underscore in the function name of `org_setup` (which is possible, but not the standard naming convention), then the problem is with the call to `add-hook` itself.  Instead of using `(org_setup)`, it should be `'org_setup`.  Try changing the call to `add-hook` as follows:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org_setup)
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution! Can you explain why `(org_setup)` doesn't work, but `'org_setup` does? My thought was that the former simply called my function.

Comment: Using the form of `(org_setup)`  as the second argument to `add-hook`, results in the immediate evaluation of that function *instead* of adding the function to the `org-mode-hook`.  Alternatively, you could have used `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (load-theme 'doom-laserwave)))`.  However, many users recommend writing a separate function to be attached to the mode hook so that inspecting the hook with `C-h v` (aka `M-x describe-variable`) is more readable and using `remove-hook` is also easier when a separate function is used.

Comment: The former calls the function, which is why the theme is always getting applied. You want to save the function itself (not its return value) in the hook to be called later.